# Android Javacv load drawables to IplImage cvLoadImage

Tags: android, image-processing, javacv

I am a total beginner in image processing. Basically, what I want to achieve is that to detect a red colour from a picture using JavaCv. After researching for a few days, from this [blog](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/javacv-simple-color-detection-using.html) when loading image from IplImage cvLoadImage it requires a string argument. How would I load an image to IplImage from android drawables? Also I would like to know how to display IplImage to ImageView. I have found [site also](http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1817059/) to display IplImage to ImageView but it confuses me. If someone would be kind here to help me please.

This the code that for IpLImage from this [blog](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/javacv-simple-color-detection-using.html):

```
    //read image
    IplImage orgImg = cvLoadImage("colordetectimage.jpg");
    //create binary image of original size
    IplImage imgThreshold = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(orgImg), 8, 1);
    //apply thresholding
    cvInRangeS(orgImg, min, max, imgThreshold);
    //smooth filter- median
    cvSmooth(imgThreshold, imgThreshold, CV_MEDIAN, 13);
    //save
    cvSaveImage("threshold.jpg", imgThreshold);
```

As you can see the `IplImage orgImg = cvLoadImage("colordetectimage.jpg");` code requires a string argument. What I would like to achieve is that it would load from android drawables, process them to detect red color and then display it on to the imageview.

Comment: Can you include the code from the links here, or a brief summary of the key points if the information included there is too long? The former should be okay in this case. It's better to have all the information here than requiring users to click to links, which may become deprecated in the future.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for you fast response! It really helps alot especially to beginners! Okay I will edit my question for a minute. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited my question now please take a look at it.